# htmlspecialchars: escape double quotes for all languages

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I have text inputs containing data from customers in all languages (most fall under the ISO-8859-1 charset, but some like Russian don't). To avoid breaking the text input in case the value contains double quotes, I use the following:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'. htmlspecialchars($client_name, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1') .'" />';
```

It works well with regular caracters. Problems arise with different charsets. For instance, with Russian, the above outputs html entities such as:

```
&#1058
```

Since our customer service uses this form, they have to see the text as it is, to make sure the fields have been correctly filled. Is there an alternative to the above code that would strip double quotes from all languages and preserve ?

Functions such as str_replace aren't what I'm looking for, because I do not want to replace the double quotes, just to display them without breaking the code.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you having your customer service people look at the HTML *source code*? Render the HTML and they'll see normal characters.

Comment: Sorry, didn't make it clear: customer service doesn't see the source code, they see the text fields. I want the text to be displayed correctly inside the text field.

Comment: The code you have should show the text correctly inside the field. If they see `&#1058` then it is probably because someone is typing that in the first place (or some other code you have is converting it to entities so you end up double escaping it).

Comment: Quentin, the data looks fine when I don't use the htmlspecialchars function - for instance in textareas. In this case the Russian caracters are displayed as they should. I'm not using the htmlspecialchars function for textarea data since the presence of a double quote wouldn't break the code.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I settled for the following function:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'. str_replace('"','&quot;',$client_name) .'" />';
```

This way I don't have any issues with various languages.